# What's the difference between realm.write and realm.beginWrite+realm.commitWrite?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

There are two ways of performing a write transaction in Realm, what's the difference between them?

1.

```
try! realm.write {
  ...
}
```

2.

```
realm.beginWrite()
...
try! realm.commitWrite()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Updated on 4/19/2017 to be more concise and to explain the advantages of choosing one over the other.***

---

Functionally, there's no difference between the two. The method `realm.write` is a more convenient method to perform write transactions, but [internally](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/RealmSwift/Realm.swift#L152), it still simply makes use of the exact same `beginWrite`/`commitWrite` transaction APIs:

```
public func write(_ block: (() throws -> Void)) throws {
    beginWrite()
    do {
        try block()
    } catch let error {
        if isInWriteTransaction { cancelWrite() }
        throw error
    }
    if isInWriteTransaction { try commitWrite() }
}
```

That being said, while `realm.write {}` is quicker and cleaner to write, there are still instances where you might want to rely on `beginWrite` / `commitWrite` instead.

`beginWrite` and `commitWrite()` are more manual, which is great if you want more control. `realm.write {}` implements its own error handling routine, but if you'd like to perform your own specific error handling, you can do so with `beginWrite` / `commitWrite` (Or alternatively, you could try enclosing `try realm.write {}` in its own `do` / `catch` block).

Another advantage to having more control is that you can implement logic that might choose to outright cancel a transaction that's already started using `cancelWrite()`.

Ultimately, it depends on the level of control you want with controlling handling specific write transactions, and how you want to organize your code. You could easily consider both depending on the complexity of the write transaction you're planning on performing.

`realm.write {}` uses closures which makes wrapping the transaction code very elegant, and minimal, but at a potential loss of the amount of control you might want. `beginWrite` / `commitWrite` gives you more control, but ultimately require you as the user to do more work in terms of handling potential errors.

---

***Original Answer***

There's absolutely no difference between the two. The method `realm.write` is simply a more convenient method to perform write transactions instead of using `beginWrite`/`commitWrite`.

In fact, if you check out [the source code for Realm Swift](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/RealmSwift/Realm.swift#L152), you'll see that `realm.write` is actually just a wrapper for `beginWrite`/`commitWrite`.

```
public func write(_ block: (() throws -> Void)) throws {
    beginWrite()
    do {
        try block()
    } catch let error {
        if isInWriteTransaction { cancelWrite() }
        throw error
    }
    if isInWriteTransaction { try commitWrite() }
}
```

So there's no difference between using the two. Both are available to you so you can pick the one that is easiest for you to integrate into your code. :)

Comment: I must be half-blind but I also see automatic transaction cancellation in case of error in the case of `try! realm.write {`.

Comment: Hopefully not! :) Yeah, `realm.write` has some additional niceties. Using `realm.beginWrite` / `realm.commitWrite` gives you ultimate manual control, but that means you're also responsible for your own error handling. (Although, this is all moot if you disregard error handling by using the `try!` keyword anyway).

Comment: I've run into oddities before by having write transactions not cancelled on error, so I think `realm.write` is safer in that regard, just like `realm.executeTransaction()` in Realm-Java.

Comment: @TiM maybe you should add your commentary about niceties in the answer body, that was exactly what my problem is. :) Thanks!

Comment: @VictorLaerte Good thinking! I'll improve my answer with the stuff we discussed in here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another case to use `beginWrite` & `commitWrite` is when you don't want to fire change notifications.
To do so, you can pass the notification token to `commitWrite` as,
`commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [token])`.

More detail is in the Realm's official article - 
[Interface-Driven Writes](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#interface-driven-writes)